# rule-based creation of sublists from list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {a, b, c, d, e, f, a, b, k, m, n, e, a, b, d}
```

and would like to create a list whose elements are those between each occurrence of `{a, b}` and `{e}`, which gives:

```
res = {{c, d}, {k, m, n}}
```

Thank you very much for ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) or [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html):

```
SequenceCases[lis, {a, b, x : Except[e] .., e} :> {x}]
```

> {{c, d}, {k, m, n}}

```
ReplaceList[lis, {___, a, b, x : Except[e] .., e, ___} :> {x}]
```

> {{c, d}, {k, m, n}}

Comment: Do you reckon that Shortest[x__] could also work?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP,  that's what I first tried. `SequenceCases[lis, {a, b, Shortest[x__], e} :> {x}]` gives, somehow, `{{c, d, e, f, a, b, k, m, n}}`.